# JTable Add new Record Dialog box is not closing Automatically after clicking save button and also the table is not Updating Automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jtable

As i said Above the JTable Add new record is not closing if we click on save button its working with cancel button but not wid SAVE  and also Data in the table is not updating untill we refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

The jtable expects the inserted data in the return json.

something like

{"Result":"OK","Record":[{"System_ID":"169","Location":"Attic","SystemName":"Server","DeviceName":"Ubuntu","Access_Level":"root","Login":"root","Password":"passw","Active":"1","Notes":"Notes go here."}]}

you can install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

and Check if you getting this error
jTable ERROR: Server must return the created Record object.